# Load json schema in postman from external file

Tags: javascript, json, postman, jsonschema

Is it possible to insert a json schema in a postman test script, where the schema is described in a Javascript file located in a defined folder?

Comment: I don't think so, but perhaps if you tell us why you want to do that, we can find a different solution for your problem :)

Comment: I would like to do tests on postman, where for every interaction I have the possibility to change the schema of the joson to be checked, where the scheme I defined before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of... You can use your collection's (or a folder) pre-request script to store a global or environment variable that holds the JSON schema (note: you can only store text so JSON.stringify is your friend in storing and JSON.parse when retreiving).

On the test script, you can retreive this variable.

So not in an external file, but in one place (per collection).

Alternatively, you can make the schema available from a webserver and use either a separate request to fetch it and put it into a variable, or do that via javascript.

Comment: I had already thought of a similar solution, the schemes are large enough to save in the environment variables.

It seems very interesting to me to call the schema with a separate request, in this case it can be realized with a local service ??